# is there any relation between the emissivity and the temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, thermal-conductivity, thermoelectricity, thermal-field-theory

I was just wondering if there is any relation between the emissivity and the temperature (i.e. temperature as a function of the emissivity).

If yes, can you write the relation and cite a reference for your answer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes emissivity depends on temperature:

$$
    \epsilon(T)= \frac{E(T)}{E_b (T)}
$$
$\epsilon$ is total hemespherical emissivity.
$E$ is the emissive power of the actual body which depend on temperature and $E_b$ is the emissive power of a blackbody: $E_b(T)=\sigma T^4$

Comment: Can you please explain the terms in more details?

Comment: @kazekage There's not much more to say here. The particular form of $E(T)$ depends heavily on the particular body you're examining, and may deviate significantly from the usual Stefan-Boltzmann form.